# Adding margin-bottom to child of a min-height container has strange effects

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The first row has a height that is much larger than the margin bottom of its `.content` div, so that the margin-bottom is contained (and should not effect anything outside of its container).  Yet, there's a gap between the two rows... very mysterious.

[See this plunker for a visual representation and code](http://plnkr.co/edit/kzhMbv?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div class="row row1">
  Row 1 (min-height: 100px)
  <div class="content">Content (margin-bottom: 10px;)</div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
  Row 2:  Why the gap?  The margin-bottom on Content stops WAY short of this div.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .row1 { min-height: 100px; }
  .row1 .content { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Notes:

- Changing `min-height` to `height` removes the gap
- Adding `overflow:hidden;` to the first row removes the gap
- I'm using Chrome on a Mac.  I didn't have a chance to test this in any other browsers (its time for lunch)

Why does this happen though?  Is it a bug?

Comment: I'm using Firefox on PC and I don't see a gap.

Comment: But both IE and Chrome have it. hmm...

Comment: Yea, my row needs to grow with dynamic content - `min-height` is required.  Overflow: hidden; might work, not sure about IE8 though.

Comment: Use `.row1 { min-height: 100px; height: x%; }`. That removes the bug. If you want everything to have a percentage height then remember to use `html,body { height: 100%; }`